# Redux not update nasted state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an array and i'm dispatching `LIKE_POST` action from child component. Redux state updated but view not updating. I'm using `Flatlist`. And using `extradata`. (Working `ADD_POST` and `DELETE_POST` actions)

action.payload returning liked post id,

In reducer:

```
    const initialState = {
        feedData: [],
        loading: false,
    };
...
//FETCH FEED
...
    case LIKE_POST:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    feedData: [
                        ...state.feedData.map((post) => {
                            if (post.id === action.payload) {
                                return {
                                    ...post,
                                    like: {
                                        count: 1,
                                        isLiked: true,
                                    },
                                };
                            }
                            return post;
                        }),
                    ],
                };
```

Logger is returning `like:1` and `isLiked:true` but view not updated.

Comment: Let's see the selector (or `useSelector` or `connect`) call you are using here as well.
Also, in general you probably should follow [the official recommendation to use redux toolkit](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-redux-toolkit-for-writing-redux-logic) instead of writing plain redux logic by hand, as in RTK reducers you can use mutating logic.
Your code in that case would become
`const found = state.feedData.find(post => post.id === action.payload); if (found) {   found.like = {count: 1, isLiked: true } }`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

I'm using `useState` hook in the component for `feedData`.  When i remove useState and directly using stored data. It's worked.

```
const feedData = useSelector(state=>state.feed.feedData)
const [data, setData] = useState(feedData) => THIS IS THE MISTAKE
```

Comment: Congratulations!